# Different column width in fc-head and fc-body of fullcalender embedded in bootstrap skelleton

Tags: fullcalendar

would be great if you could help me with this:

I included a basic fullcalendar in my website (which is using bootstrap 4) by following this documentation:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/

The header looks fine, the column width is the same for each day. But the columns below the header are totally messed up [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4GrE.png)

I tried to fix this by using "table-layout:fixed;" as suggested in some other posts, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that replicates the issue ? Thanks!

Comment: While I was creating the fiddle I found the issue: I have some layouts refering to td and tr which are competing with the fullcalender layout. !important doesn't work, my solution is to create classes for the other tables on my website so that I can change the layout based on those classes. Thanks.